# display reports while minimizing resolution issues

Tags: tables, screen-resolution, charts

I'm building reports and dashboard interface for customer use that should eventually serve many users with many different screens and different resulutions.

I build the report with ssrs-2008 tool. This tool has a major issue - it doesn't use pixels to calculate the screen size, instead it uses points. This means that different users see the reports in different sizes.

My question is how can I minimize the effects of the resolution issues in my reports? Especially when displaying charts and tables.

Comment: Is this for the web or native application?

Comment: sorry for not mention it , this is for web browsers (IE, Chrome and FF)

Comment: Are the report interactive -- with click events for drill down? Or can you render the report as a PDF and have their pdf reader deal with it.

Comment: The reports are usually interactive. with icons and clicks. the common reports are tables and charts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, someone with a 1920px widescreen is going to see more than a someone with 1280px of horizontal space. I presume one objective is to minimize the amount of horizontal scroll users have to perform. So here's a couple of things that come to mind:

- Re-order the columns by importance/relevance to the user.
- Allow users to re-arrange columns as they see fit.
- Anticipate the data and wrap text where appropriate.